# How do you write "love , without you I'm just a person"

Tags: translation

I need this in korean for a poem I'm writing

Comment: I see a space right before the comma. Are you translating Chinese into Korean?

Comment: What have you tried to translate this? Do you have any incomplete translations you want to correct?

Comment: By "love", do you mean the abstract noun *love*, or do you mean it in the sense of 'my love'/'the person I love'?

Comment: No , not Chinese ! English to korean @Константин Ваh

Comment: Love as in calling someone "my love"  @user17915

Comment: Is it correct to say : 사랑 , 너 없으면 난 근양 사람이야 ( I'm still learning korean so i don't know if the spelling is right )

Comment: Using 사랑 solely cannot possibly mean "my love." "내 사랑" ("my love") will do.

Comment: I don't quite get the "`I'm just a person`" part. Without the "`love`," "`I`" is a person; what would "`I`" with the "`love`" be, then?

Comment: Its kinda like a wordplay , to say : love , without you I'm just a person // here it can mean without the feeling of love (사랑 ) I'm just a person ( 사람 ) // but in this sentence i (as the poet ) assign the feeling of love to/for a person who makes me loved !

Answer (score 2):

Trying to convey another person's thoughts and feelings through a translation is difficult, especially in poetry.
However the following is my interpretation of the sentence, "Love,  without you I'm just a person."

사랑아, 네가 없이는 나는 그저 사람일 뿐이다

I chose to emphasize "just a person" with (으)ㄹ 뿐이다 which indicates only one available course of action or state.

I hope I helped convey your feelings adequately.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are better ways to illustrate that sentence but the most simplest is: 사랑, 난 너없이는 그냥 사람/인간이다.